# ASP.NET MVC route matching.

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

In ASP.NET MVC routing (not web API), how do I match any integer in the beginning of a route and not after it.

For example, I see examples that mention how to match /website/Product/{id} - here a ProductController is created with id parameter and constraints are specified on the id parameter.

However, I'm trying to match a route that looks this way - 
/website/{top-level-id}/Product/{id}

The top-level-id can be any integer. Any thoughts on how to go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
     name: "WithTopId",
     url: "{topId}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
     defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
     constraints: new { topId = "^[0-9]*$", id = "^[0-9]*$" }
 );
```

Then just put this route above the default route.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a route like this

```
routes.MapRoute("TopLevelProduct", "{topLevelId}/Product/{id}", 
           new { controller = "Product", action = "Index" });
```

You can replace Index with whatever action you want to hit and if you ids to have optional defaults (I've renamed your top level identifier as it's awkward having those hyphens in C#

```
routes.MapRoute("TopLevelProduct", "{topLevelId}/Product/{id}", 
       new { controller = "Product", action = "Index", topLevelId = 0, id = 0 });
```